# Can't join areas. I only see "Swap Areas"

Tags: 3d-view

Using 2.82a. 
I made some accidental area subdivisions and I wanted to join them. 
But now, right-clicking on the area line, I just see "Swap Areas".
[image]
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I opened a [ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T76771) on the blender's support and the problem is that to join the areas, the areas have to be the same height (vertically) or width (horizontally).
So there was a 4th small area on the top of the middle area which was avoiding to join the vertical areas:
[image]

This way I need first to join the top area as described in the blender support ticket: 
[image]